# Why is my text-align : center not working in my dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, text-align

I'm trying to create a drop-down menu but my text-align command wouldn't seem to work (same applies with font-size and other text-related codes). I tried putting my text-align codes in nav ul li and nothing seem to happen. I've also tried putting it on the main .drop-down menu on CSS but it still has no changes. Can anyone help me out here? I couldn't figure out the reasoning behind this.

My HTML and CSS codes are:

```css
nav{
    flex:1;
    text-align: right;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #E6C7F3;
    
}

.dropdown-menu{
    display: none;
    
 
}
nav ul li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:black;
    opacity: .8;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    
}

.dropdown-menu ul{
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;

}

.dropdown-menu ul li{
    width: 0px;
    left: -58;
    bottom: 5;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="image/durra.png" class="logo"></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html">SHOP</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Bestsellers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>    
                    <li><a href="feedback.html">FEEDBACK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>    
                </ul>    
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is your dropdown menu? This isn't a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi First you have to add **padding  to ul under dropdown-menu**. and then **set width of li item to 100%**. Please refer below code.

```
.dropdown-menu ul {
   display: block;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding: 10px 0 0;
}

.dropdown-menu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    left: -58;
    bottom: 5;
    padding: 10px 0;
    /* padding-right: 40px; */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

text-align works with a element having width. But you have used width: 0px . So it's pretty obvious you cannot use alignment there.

Comment: I tried removing width: 0px and added the text-align code but still has no changes.